# Installing Gnome on OpenBSD 6.3

Tags: gnome, openbsd

I want to install  Gnome on OpenBSD 6.3. The instructions I've found far refer to earlier versions of OpenBSD and produce error messages. I'm working from a clean install of OpenBSD 6.3 that I did yesterday. I have all the gnome basic and gdm desktop packages downloaded and installed.
This is my /etc/rc.conf.local file:

```
#multicast_host=YES
#pkg_scripts="messagebus dbus_daemon avahi_daemon gdm"
#xdm_flags=""
#gnome_enable=YES
#gdm_enable=YES
```

Typing "gdm" produces this error message:

```
gdm[50260]: Couldn’t connect to system bus: Could not connect: No such file or directory
```

Am I correct in thinking this means that the operating system can't find messagebus? Also, I'm an OpenBSD newbie - am I correct in thinking that messagebus is a more recent program to do what used to be handled by dbus_daemon? I think I don't need both, but removing dbus_daemon had no effect. My environment does not have  pkg_scripts folder in it. If pkg_scripts is a folder, where is it?
Also, I don't want to start gnome at boot. I only want to run it when I need it. Ideally, I'd just like to type "gdm" (or whatever it's supposed to be) on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the `#` sign needs to be removed as when proceeds the comment it is quiet 
or not recognized I do not want sshd by default so my rc.conf.local is --->>

```
sshd_flags=NO
multicast_host=YES
pkg_scripts="messagebus dbus_daemon avahi_daemon gdm"
```

You see no `#` sign preceding, although presently not sure if dbus_daemon needs to be there. Anyway with Unix anytime a space is between words you must have "     "
encompassing the statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing a clean installation of OpenBSD, please reinstall the system again and follow the official instructions. You don't need to follow external guides. Install the gnome metapackage with `pkg_add -i gnome` and then read everything within `/usr/local/share/doc/pkg-readmes/`.

Those files will tell you what is needed in `rc.conf.local`. To run manually a desktop you need to use the file `.xinitrc` and the proper line with the desktop (not with the session manager). `startx` is the command to start the graphical session.